# How to scale an image for a canvas pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I want to fill a Canvas with an Image and scale it to a certain width beforehand.

I am trying to achieve an effect where an image in the foreground of the canvas can be erased with the mouse to view an image in the background. This is why I need to use a pattern to fill my canvas instead of just using drawImage(). Everything works apart from the scaling of the foreground image. Here is my code for generating the pattern:

```
var blueprint_background = new Image();
blueprint_background.src = "myfunurl"; 
blueprint_background.width = window.innerWidth;
blueprint_background.onload = function(){
    var pattern = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat");
    context.fillStyle = pattern;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, 768);
    context.fill();
};
```

This does exactly what it should do, except that the image keeps its original size.
As you see, I want the image to scale to window.innerWidth (which has the value 1920 when logging it).
If needed, I can provide the rest of the code, but since the error is most likely in this snippet, I decided not to post the rest.

**EDIT**: Here is my full code with the suggested changes. The front ground image now displays over the full width, however the erasing does not work anymore.

JavaScript (Note that I use jQuery instead of $):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var cwidth = window.innerWidth;
var cheight = 768;

function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
        var canvas = {};
        canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
        canvas.node.width = width || 100;
        canvas.node.height = height || 100;
        parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
        return canvas;
    }

    function init(canvas, fillColor) {
        var ctx = canvas.context;
        canvas.isDrawing = true;
        jQuery('#canvas').children().css('position:absolute; top: ' + jQuery('#Top_bar').height() + 'px');
        // define a custom fillCircle method
        ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
            this.fillStyle = fillColor;
            this.beginPath();
            this.moveTo(x, y);
            this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            this.fill();
        };

        // bind mouse events
        canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
               return;
            }
            var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var y = e.pageY - jQuery('#Top_bar').outerHeight();
            var radius = 30;
            var fillColor = '#ff0000';
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
        };

    }

    var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    jQuery('#canvas').css('position:absolute; top: ' + jQuery('#Top_bar').height() + 'px');
    var canvas = createCanvas(container, cwidth, cheight);
    init(canvas, '#ddd');

var fgimg = document.getElementById("fgimg");
fgimg.width = cwidth;

var context = canvas.node.getContext("2d");
let canvasP = document.getElementById("pattern");
canvasP.width = window.innerWidth;
canvasP.height = 768; 
let ctxP = canvasP.getContext("2d");
ctxP.drawImage( fgimg, 0, 0,window.innerWidth,768 );    

context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(canvasP,"no-repeat");
context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

});
```

CSS:

```
#canvas {
    background:url(http://ulmke-web.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Header-6.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 768px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas">
<canvas id="pattern">
</div>

<div style="display:none">
<img id="fgimg" src=" http://ulmke-web.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Header-5.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use two canvases. On the first one you draw your image and you use this canvas as an image to create the pattern. In order to scale the image you scale the size of the first canvas `#pattern` in my example.

For example you can do this for a 10/10 image:

```
canvasP.width = 10;
canvasP.height = 10; 
ctxP.drawImage( redpoint, 2.5, 2.5 );
```

or you can do this for a 20/20 image:

```
canvasP.width = 20;
canvasP.height = 20; 
ctxP.drawImage( redpoint, 5, 5,10,10 );
```

Furthermore, in my example I'm adding a little margin around the image.

```js
let canvasP = document.getElementById("pattern");
  if (canvasP && canvasP.getContext) {
  let ctxP = canvasP.getContext("2d");
     /*canvasP.width = 10;
      canvasP.height = 10; 
      ctxP.drawImage( redpoint, 2.5, 2.5 ); */
      
      canvasP.width = 20;
      canvasP.height = 20; 
      ctxP.drawImage( redpoint, 5, 5,10,10 ); 
  }
  
  let canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas");
  if (canvas1 && canvas1.getContext) {
  let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
   if (ctx1) {

    ctx1.fillStyle = ctx1.createPattern(canvasP,"repeat");
    ctx1.fillRect(0,0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
       
    }
  }
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
 <img id="redpoint" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
<canvas id="pattern"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Using your code, I can get the image into the frontground in the dimensions I want it in. However, the code I use for erasing, which worked on my code, does not work on yours, sadly. Any possibility you could help me with that?

Comment: I would like to help you buit I need to see your code, A working example

Comment: I have added my whole code to the main question. Thanks in advance.